# Spark Dataset write() method returns error

Tags: xml, csv, hadoop, apache-spark, dataset

I am trying to load XML file using Databricks library and write the data to the file but I am unable to write the output `data(array<string>)` to the csv file.

I get following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: CSV data source does not support array<string> data type.
```

when I print the Dataset it prints likes this:

```
+--------------------+
|             orgname|
+--------------------+
|[Muncy, Geissler,...|
|[Muncy, Geissler,...|
|[Knobbe Martens O...|
|[null, Telekta La...|
|[McAndrews, Held ...|
|[Notaro, Michalos...|
|                null|
|[Cowan, Liebowitz...|
|                null|
|[Kunzler Law Grou...|
|[null, null, Klei...|
|[Knobbe, Martens,...|
|[Merchant & Gould...|
|                null|
|[Culhane Meadows ...|
|[Culhane Meadows ...|
|[Vista IP Law Gro...|
|[Thompson & Knigh...|
|  [Fish & Tsang LLP]|
|                null|
+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception should be self explanatory. You cannot write an array to `CSV` file.

You have to concatenate it into a single string:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.concat_ws

val separator: String = ";"  // Choose appropriate one in your case

df.withColumn("orgname", concat_ws(separator, $"orgname")).write.csv(...)
```

Comment: great job brother